# How to authenticate against a Docker Hub organization repository

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I am one of the owners of a Docker Hub organization. We want to start pushing images built on GitHub to one of our repositories on Docker Hub.

The question: how to authenticate?

Of course, we could store the personal access token of one of the org owners as a GitHub secret but that would be totally weird. However, there doesn’t seem to be an option to create an org token or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed by Docker support that this is currently not possible. Follow-up request: https://github.com/docker/roadmap/issues/461

Answer (score 0):

Docker has support for [security scoped tokens](https://www.docker.com/blog/level-up-security-with-scoped-access-tokens/) to create limited PATs. Unfortunately, that's a paid feature. You can follow that and see many other linked issues in [roadmap issue #115](https://github.com/docker/roadmap/issues/115).

Comment: Unfortunately this is for user account only. OP is talking about the organization access token which does not seem available. I can access the user account repos just fine, but there's no option for an organization AFAIK. If this is wrong, please let me and others know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I couldn't see my organisation's repos when authenitcating to GitHub from Docker Hub.

I went to the Organisation Settings on GitHub to see if authorisation was approved.
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JljiU.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW2Bf.png).

1. Click on your profile image at the top right hand side of GitHub. Click on "Your Organisations".
2. Select the Organisation.
3. Click Settings.
4. Click OAuth application policy.
5. Approve Docker Hub Builder.